# SQL query to find names of student who took only 4- credits courses

Tags: mysql, database

There are 3 tables

```
Students (sid:integer, sname:string, age:integer) 
Courses (cid:integer, cname:integer, credits:integer) 
Grades(sid:integer, cid:integer, grade:string)
```

i would like to get students who only take courses with 4 credits

I have tried

```
SELECT sname FROM Students JOIN Grades ON Student.sid = Grades.sid
                           JOIN Grades ON Course.cid = Grades.cid
WHERE credits = 4
```

Comment: Please add sample data and expected result as text. For homework questions it would good if you showed what you have tried.

Comment: alright i have added my attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the tables, `group by` student and set the condition in the `having` clause:

```
SELECT s.sid, s.sname 
FROM Students s 
INNER JOIN Grades g ON g.sid = s.sid
INNER JOIN Courses c ON c.cid = g.cid
GROUP BY s.sid, s.sname
HAVING SUM(c.credits <> 4) = 0
```

Comment: shouldnt the `HAVING SUM(c.credits <> 4) =0`
be `HAVING SUM(c.credits = 4) = 0`?

Comment: `HAVING SUM(c.credits = 4) = 0` will return students who never took courses with 4 credits.